# How to check if fs.read() is empty

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, filesystems, fs

I need to check whether a file is empty before I can put it in `JSON.parse()`.

```
if (fs.exists('path/to/file')) { // true
   return JSON.parse(fs.read('path/to/file'));
}
```

I know that the file exists by `fs.exists()`, but how can I check if the file contains no strings before I can put it in `JSON.parse()`?

```
JSON.parse(fs.read('path/to/file'));
```

Returns:

> SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (fs.exists('path/to/file')) {
    if (fs.read('path/to/file').length === 0) {
        //Code to be executed if the file is empty
    } else {
        return JSON.parse(fs.read('path/to/file'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was also looking for a solution to find out if the file is empty or not. Found the below code and it works great.

```
const stat = fs.statSync('./path/to/file');
console.log(stat.size);
```

You can check if the stat.size is 0 and do your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that is not deprecated.
just checking for statSync will crash if file doesn't exist.

```
if(!fs.existsSync('./path/to/file') || fs.statSync('./path/to/file').size == 0) {
  // file doesn't exist or is empty.
} else {
  // process a non empty file
}
```